# Extremally disconnected space and separating function

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Suppose $\forall U, V \subset X$ open, disjoint sets in $X$ it holds
>   that $\overline{U} \cap \overline{V} = \emptyset$ as well.
>
> I want to show that for every two disjoint open sets, $U, V$ there is a continuous function $f: X \to [0,1]$
>   that separates $U, V$. That is, $f(U) \subset \{0\}, f(V) \subset
>  \{1\}$.

My attempt:

If $U, V$ are as above, than $ \overline{V} \subset X - \overline{U}$ and $ \overline{U} \subset X - \overline{V}$ and these are open sets in $X$.

Moreover $X = X - \overline{U} \cup X - \overline{V}$.

Setting $A = X - \overline{U} \cap X - \overline{V}$, we can define:

$
  f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
                                   0 & \text{if $x \in X - \overline{V}$} \\
                                   \frac{1}{2} & \text{if $x \in A$} \\
  1 & \text{if $x \in X - \overline{U}$}
  \end{cases}
$

And it seems $f$ is continuous. However I feel shaky about this; what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems like the definition of your function doesn't make sense. If $x\in A$, then $x\in X-\overline U$ and $x\in X-\overline V$, so is $f(x)$ 0, .5, or 1? Did you mean the following? $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0\quad x\in\overline U\\.5\quad x\in A \\ 1 \quad x\in \overline V\end{cases}$$

Comment: hey, no that's not what I mean; my map is well defined as $A$ stands for the intersection of the above sets. Your map may not be continuous as $\overline{U}$ isn't open

Comment: I agree that my map isn't continuous, but I still don't see how your map is well defined. Suppose $x\in A$. Then $x\in X-\overline A$ and $x\in X-\overline B$.  So what is $f(x)$. Maybe instead you meant that $f(x)=\begin{cases}0\quad x\in(X-\overline V-A)\\.5\quad x\in A\\1 \quad x\in(x-\overline U-A)\end{cases}$. This way, no element $x$ matches the cases for more than one part of the function.